# Google Indoor Maps custom marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web, google-api

Company where I working, have some devices in shopping centers. And Google have some service: "Google Indoor Maps". It's look like building map. So, I want to show markers for our devices on this map. 
There is a little, but very important difference between simple custom marker on Google maps, and marker on Google indoor maps - floors. If I add simple marker, it will be able on all floors of the scheme. It's must be look like this:

**On the 3 floor marker available (godzilla pic)**
[image]

**And not available on another floor**
[image]